# Solution environment with empty space below it

Tags: exam

In exam class, I want the solution environment with no line below it like this-
Solution- this is the first line, second line should start from below this after - and third line also should start after - ( below solution there should be empty space)

But I am getting-

```
Solution-this is first line
This is second line
This is third line
```

[image]

```
%%%%%%SOLUTION%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\setlength{\parindent}{200pt}\setlength{\labelsep}{3cm}}
%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\Ans[2][]{%
   \vspace{0.2cm}\par\noindent
   {\leftskip-37pt
    \textbf{Ans-}{#2}\par}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\unframedsolutions%% for solution not in box use package option[answers]exam
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\par\noindent\leftskip-48pt\textbf{Ans-}\hspace{2mm}}
%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Have you tried something?

Comment: %%%%%%SOLUTION%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\setlength{\parindent}{200pt}\setlength{\labelsep}{3cm}}
%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\Ans[2][]{%
   \vspace{0.2cm}\par\noindent
   {\leftskip-37pt
    \textbf{Ans-}{#2}\par}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\unframedsolutions%% for solution not in box use package option[answers]exam
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\par\noindent\leftskip-48pt\textbf{Ans-}\hspace{2mm}}
%%%%%%%%%%  I have tried this but since solution is not list environment this not getting the below solution empty